# curl triggering open_basedir

Tags: php, php-curl, apache2.4, php-7.4, open-basedir

I have a php (php-fpm) script `script1.php` running in `/var/www/html/folder1/script1.php`, protected with `open_basedir` "/var/www/html/folder1".

From that script, I call a 2nd script `script2.php` located in `/var/www/html/folder2/script2.php` through `php-curl`.

I call script2 using its public load balancer IP, yet, I get an error from script1, open_basedir in effect. I'm not sure why that's happening since curl is http://, not file://, and shouldn't resolve the file system the way it does. Or should it? I don't intend to change that open_basedir parameter. What's my best course of action?

Comment: Curl returns the error from script1 because you call script2 from script1 so script1 gets the response of the error. you have your open_basedir setup wrong.

Comment: script2.php is called through a standard http request. they are not in the same basedir because they are 2 different websites, just hosted on the same localhost.

Comment: Whoops my bad, misinterpreted the question, can you show us the php.ini, are you sure there are not any other `open_basedir` active?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I worked it out. Even though php has different child Pids for each script execution, it still considered script2 being called from script1 *directly*, hence falling within `open_basedir` jurisdiction. I'm not sure why, since the curl call is emulating an http request and therefore should spawn a brand new process...

Either way, I forced `/var/www/html/folder2` into a 2nd php-fpm pool, so not only the children have different PIDs but also the parent process as well. Now curl calls script2, and a separate context is created to handle it. This way, `openbase_dir` is recalculated correctly and my problem was solved.

Creating a 2nd `php-fpm` pool is really easy. I use Apache 2.4 but here is an example for nginx that I loosely followed for this exercise: https://www.vultr.com/docs/use-php-fpm-pools-to-secure-multiple-web-sites/